# How to read date present under td div

Tags: jquery

I have got the following div

```
<table>
<tbody>
   <tr >
      <td class="dvd_brdb">
         <p class="PL10">
            <a href="fdsf" class="bl_12"><b>APM Industries</b></a>
         </p>
      </td>
      <td class="dvd_brdb">
         <p class="PL30"><span>06-Nov-2015</span></p>
      </td>
      <td class="dvd_brdb">
         <p class="PR20 FR">52.50</p>
      </td>
      <td class="dvd_brdb">
         <p class="PR15 FR  r_12">-0.94</p>
      </td>
      <td class="dvd_brdb">
         <p class="PR15 FR">59.90</p>
      </td>
      <td class="dvd_brdb">
         <p class="PR15 FR">32.55</p>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="#f6f6f6">
      <td class="dvd_brdb">
         <p class="PL10">
            <a href="jhg" class="bl_12"><b>Apollo Tyres</b></a>
         </p>
      </td>
      <td class="dvd_brdb">
         <p class="PL30"><span>30-Oct-2015</span></p>
      </td>
      <td class="dvd_brdb">
         <p class="PR20 FR">190.95</p>
      </td>
      <td class="dvd_brdb">
         <p class="PR15 FR  gr_12">0.24</p>
      </td>
      <td class="dvd_brdb">
         <p class="PR15 FR">249.45</p>
      </td>
      <td class="dvd_brdb">
         <p class="PR15 FR">154.70</p>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to read `Company Name` and the `Date` this way

```
$("tbody tr").each(function(){
    var company_name = $(this).find("td").find(".PL10").find(".bl_12").text();
    var date_res = $(this).find("td:eq(2)").find(".dvd_brdb").find(".PL30").text();
    console.log(company_name);
    console.log(date_res);
});
```

I am able to get the `company name` , but facing issues with respect to getting `date` .

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/86gef8qa/14/)

Comment: `$(this).find('.dvd_brdb span').text()`, [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/86gef8qa/15/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tbody tr").each(function(){
    var company_name = $(this).find(".bl_12").text();

    var date_res = $(this).find(".PL30").text();

    console.log(company_name);
    console.log(date_res);
});
```

This selector will do.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/86gef8qa/16/)

Answer (score 0):

When you do

`$(this).find("td:eq(2)")`

the result is already `td.dvd_brdb`.

So just remove `.find(".dvd_brdb")` from `$(this).find("td:eq(2)").find(".dvd_brdb").find(".PL30").text();` and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

i update your code like following.

```
$("tbody tr").each(function(){

    var company_name = $(this).find("td").find(".PL10").find(".bl_12").text();

    var date_res = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
    console.log(company_name);
    console.log(date_res);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/86gef8qa/18/

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var date_res = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").find(".PL30").find("span").text();
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/86gef8qa/20/)